# Datatables first column is a string, how to convert to Datetime?

Tags: jquery, datatables

It appears that the first column in my data is being sorted by ASC. The data needs to be sorted from oldest date to newest date IE 11/15/2019 then 5/5/2020 5/6/2020 then 5/12/2020, I think I need to convert the info coming from the first column to a dateTime but I am unaware on how to do so.

[image]

```
  "order": [[1, "asc"]], // First column sorted by ASC
"columns": [
                { "name": "ID", "className": "click user-details hidden", "data": "Personnel_Id" },
                { "name": "CREATED_DATE", "className": "click user-details", "data": "CreatedDate"},// This is the column that needs the sorting to be by dateTime?
```

Comment: Consider this, might help: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/45692/how-to-date-sort-as-date-instead-of-string

Comment: If you need more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also look at https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type to set the Column type to `date` *Date / time values. Note that DataTables' built in date parsing uses Javascript's `Date.parse()` method which supports only a very limited subset of dates. Additional date format support can be added through the use of plug-ins.*

Comment: This may also help; how to use the moment.js library to parse dates automatically in datatables (just include the moment.js library, the plugin code on this page, and follow the one line in the "Example" on this page to denote what format dates to expect): https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment

Comment: Thank you all, what ended up being the answer was using "type": "date" in the column where the string output could be converted to DateTime output. Thank you all.